# Add increment in the returned id from database in c#

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio, sql-insert

I've applied a query to get rows count based on two conditions. Now what I need to do is to add an increment in the returned value and show it in a `TextBox`.

For example, if the returned result is `1` then the value in the `TextBox` should be `2`, and if row count is `2` then value in the `TextBox` should be shown `3` and so on.

Here is my rows count query:

```
string query = "select count(PID) as PID from tblPatientRevisits where PID = '" + Convert.ToInt32(tbPID.Text) + "'";
```

And what I've already tried to show incremented value in textbox is:

```
if (dt.Rows.Count >= 0){
    int VisitNo = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[0][0].ToString());
    int ReVisitNo = VisitNo++;
    ReVisitNo = Convert.ToInt32(tbRevisitID.Text);
}
```

How can I add increment in returned rows count value?

Comment: Your code is a little hard to follow.  You declare `VisitNo` and initialize it from `RevisitNo` on one line, and the immediately assign it a new value based on what's in `tbRevisitID` on the next line of code. If you are trying to put the value of `VisitNo` into `tbRevisitID`, then your assignment is backwards. Try `tbRevisitID.Text=VisitNo.ToString();`

Comment: @Flydog57 sorry that was confusing and I've corrected the line. Actually, I have two tables in first table I have "VisitNo" Column and in 2nd Table I've "ReVisitNo" Column. So what I am trying to do is that when the patient comes for the second time in hospital then the patient could not be registered again, instead the revisit no will be generated in 2nd table against the patient ID. I just want to add increment in VisitNo if the patient comes multiple times for checkup.

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection - check out [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/)

Answer (score 2):

Well, you use a post increment when writing `RevisitNo++`. That is why `RevisitNo` is incremented by one *after* the assignment. I.e. `VisitNo` gets the value assigned `RevisitNo` has before the increment. You can use pre increment, to assingn the incremented value.

```
...
int VisitNo = ++RevisitNo;
...
```

Further information can be found in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/arithmetic-operators).

Comment: Thank you man. This worked for me. Actually I was confused because too much work burden. Therefore I asked a question here.

Comment: @muhammadnoman: By the way, get used to using pre-increment rather than post-increment. In general, it's closer to what you are thinking (as was the case here). And, although it's not always more efficient, it's never less efficient than post-increment.  When I write a simple `for` loop, it is almost always like this `for(var i = 0; i < 0; ++i) { /* ... */}`

Comment: Yes, I get it and I am thinking to change my code and to use for loop for increment purpose. For loop is the best way.